# How can I query MongoDB with date range using mgo and Go?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Hi I have a collection named "my_sales" having fields product_name, price, sale_date.

My doc looks like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5458b6ee09d76eb7326df3a4"),
    "product_name" : product1,
    "price" : 200,
    "sale_date" : ISODate("2014-11-04T11:22:19.589Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5458b6ee09d76eb7326df3a4"),
    "product_name" : product1,
    "price" : 200,
    "sale_date" : ISODate("2014-11-04T11:22:19.589Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5458b6ee09d76eb7326df3a4"),
    "product_name" : product1,
    "price" : 200,
    "sale_date" : ISODate("2014-11-04T11:22:19.589Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5458b6ee09d76eb7326df3a4"),
    "product_name" : product1,
    "price" : 200,
    "sale_date" : ISODate("2014-11-05T11:22:19.589Z")
}
```

I tried in mongo shell like this

```
 db.my_sales.find({ sale_date: { $gt: ISODate("2014-11-04"), $lt: new ISODate("2014-11-05") });
```

It giving the correct result. Now I need to query same thing using golang 
I tried like this

```
 var sales_his []Sale
 err := c.Find(bson.M{"sale_date":bson.M{ "$gt": "ISODate("+date_from+")", "$lt": "ISODate("+date_to+")" }    }).All(&sales_his)
```

Its giving null result please help

Comment: Check this [Date-Range-Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65045727/basic-between-dates-queries-gte-lte-etc/67346735#67346735)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

mgo supports [time.Time](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) for BSON dates.

So if your struct looks like this:

```
type Sale struct {
    ProductName string    `bson:"product_name"`
    Price       int       `bson:"price"`
    SaleDate    time.Time `bson:"sale_date"`
}
```

Then you can query it like this:

```
fromDate := time.Date(2014, time.November, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
toDate := time.Date(2014, time.November, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

var sales_his []Sale
err = c.Find(
    bson.M{
        "sale_date": bson.M{
            "$gt": fromDate,
            "$lt": toDate,
        },
    }).All(&sales_his)
```

Comment: It was actually so simple. Can you give me the sample which we can input dynamic value ?

Answer (score 4):

I have new way to query date range:

```
// convert to date
fromTime := time.Unix(1509358405981/1000, 0)     

// Convert date to ObjectID with time    
fromObjectBson := bson.NewObjectIdWithTime(fromTime)

// condition     
bson.M{"_id":bson.M{"$gt": fromObjectBson}}
```

This will speedup your query.

Comment: This filters by the `_id` property, but asker wants to filter by the `sale_date` property.

Comment: You can generate other ObjectId.

Answer (score -1):

You Can also check this out. If you are using this method then use parse:

```
db.getCollection('user').find({
    createdOn: {
        $gt: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
```

Function without parsing: Get values using string

```
db, err := GetDB()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer db.Session.Close()

var date []models.User

coll := db.C(constants.USERTABLE)

findQuery := bson.M{"createdOn": bson.M{"$gt": echo.FromDate, "$lt": echo.ToDate}}

shared.BsonToJSONPrint(findQuery)

err = coll.Find(findQuery).All(&date)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return date, nil
}
```