# Basic between dates queries $gte, $lte, etc

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I'm having an issue with correct time formatting for my mongo query.

My questions are these:

- Is `time.Time` the right go type for mongo ISODate object?
- Why is my time parsing seeming to parse a completely different date?

Here's a complete example of what i've got going.

```
package main

import (
    // "fmt"
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

// Here's a JSON of the record as it is in the db
// { 
//  "_id" : ObjectId("5fa467af036d5f46914c423c"), 
//  "subscriptionRuleId" : "email@email", 
//  "eventDateTime" : ISODate("2020-11-05T20:59:27.096+0000"), 
//  "eventType" : "string-with-event-type", 
//  "passportAtlas" : "a long string", 
//  "_class" : "com.proj.info.model.dto.EventLog"
// }

type eventLog struct {
    SubscriptionRuleID string `json:"subscriptionRuleId,omitempty" bson:"subscriptionRuleId"`
    EventType string `json:"eventType" bson:"eventType"`
    EventDateTime time.Time `json:"eventDateTime" bson:"eventDateTime"`
    PassportAtlas string `json:"passportAtlas" bson:"passportAtlas`
}

func main() {
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)

    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    err = client.Ping(ctx, nil)

    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    collection := client.Database("compose").Collection("eventLog")

    df := "2006-02-04"
    dateFrom, _ := time.Parse(df, "2020-11-20")
    dateTo, _ := time.Parse(df, "2020-11-21")

    // This does not seem to work. 
    // A log of the dates gives me the wrong dates

    log.Printf("\nFROM: %v\nTO: %v", dateFrom, dateTo)
    // OUTPUTS:
    // FROM: 2020-01-09 00:20:00 +0000 UTC
    // TO: 2020-01-10 00:21:00 +0000 UTC

    // Notice the dates are formatted wrong in the log.
    // Even though the dates are wrong, I would still match
    // Records with those wrong dates as i've got tens of thousands
    // over the last few years...
 
    query := bson.M{
        "eventDateTime": bson.M{
            "$gte": dateFrom,
            "$lt": dateTo,
        },
    }

    cur, err := collection.Find(ctx, query)

    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    defer cur.Close(context.Background())

    var eventLogs []eventLog

    for cur.Next(ctx) {
        var eventLog eventLog
        cur.Decode(&eventLog)
        eventLogs = append(eventLogs, eventLog)
    }

    if err := cur.Err(); err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    log.Printf("num records: %v", len(eventLogs))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

BSON is simply binary JSON. MongoDB queries are BSON document constructed using similar constructs, by using `bson.M` (which is a map[string]interface{}) for objects and slices of values for arrays. There is also a `bson.D` type that can be used to construct objects that preserve ordering of its fields.

API documentation for the bson package explains most of the things you should know. The most important thing is that Go types are mapped to their bson equivalents in the way you expect them. Bson dates map to time.Time.

Using your example:

```
query:=bson.M{"eventDateTime":bson.M{"$gte": fromDate, "$lt":toDate}}
```

where `fromDate` and `toDate` are `time.Time` values.

As another example, an $in query can be written as:

```
query:=bson.M{"field":bson.M{"$in":[]string{"value1","value2"}}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why that didn't click for me yesterday. I understand the bson situation now. I have updated my question to reflect your correct query and provide some more info... now my issue is that it's not seeming to format my dates to the correct date?

Comment: Use time.Time values, do not convert them to string. Mongodb does not store dates as string, but when you format dates, it will compare a date value in the db with a string value, which will not match. Just use time.Time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to show how we can use the Date Range to search documents in MongoDB using `$gte` and `$lte`

Here we are passing the `CourseSearch` as a parameter which will be populated from the frontend/UI.

The backend service will search data in `Course` collection.

```go
type CourseSearch struct {
    Subject     string          `json:"subject,omitempty" bson:"subject,omitempty"`
    System      string          `json:"system,omitempty" bson:"system,omitempty"`
    FromDate    time.Time       `json:"from_date,omitempty" bson:"from_date"`
    ToDate      time.Time       `json:"to_date,omitempty" bson:"to_date"`
}
```

```go
func SearchByDate(ctx context.Context, searchCriteria *CourseSearch) {

    fromDate := searchCriteria.FromDate
    toDate := searchCriteria.ToDate

    database := db.Conn.Database("Education")
    metadataCollection := database.Collection("Course")
    cursor, err := metadataCollection.Find(
        ctx,
        bson.D{
            {"subject", searchCriteria.Subject},
            {"system", searchCriteria.System},
            {"duration", bson.D{{"$gte", fromDate}, {"$lt", toDate}} },
        })
```

Comment: what if my time format recieved from user is 2023-12-25